# Non-string types in AngularJS directive attributes

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a properties pane, where the number of properties can vary depending on which object is selected.

I have created by own directive called `property` that displays the name and the value of a property, using code like this:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div class="properties-pane" ng-controller="PropertiesPane">
    <div ng-repeat="property in properties">
      <property name="{{property.name}}" value="{{property.value}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simple, isn't it? This works just fine, except that `property.value` will be converted to a string (as it's an attribute on a DOM element). What am I to do if the property value is some other data type? For example an object. See the rest of the implementation (in Coffeescript):

```
MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])

MyApp.controller 'PropertiesPane', ($scope) ->
  $scope.properties = [
    # Note that value is an object, not a string:
    {name: 'First', value: {x:0, y:0, z:42}},
    {name: 'Second', value: {x:0, y:20, z:0}},
    {name: 'Third', value: {x:1, y:1, z:1}},
  ]

MyApp.directive 'property', ($compile) ->
  restrict: 'E'
  transclude: false
  replace: true
  scope: {name: '@name', value: '@value'}
  template: '<div>{{name}} {{value.x}}, {{value.y}}, {{value.z}}</div>'
  #                          ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^
  #   this doesn't work as value is a string, not an object
```

As value.x, y and z are undefined on a string, the result is of course:

First , ,
Second , ,
Third , ,

The output I want is:

First 0, 0, 42
Second 0, 20, 0
Third 1, 1, 1

I suspect there's something fundamentally wrong in my thinking of how to programatically add elements. What's the Angularish way to implement something like this?

**EDIT: Solution**

To refer to `value` as an object by reference instead of as a string value, use `=` instead of `@` in the directive:

```
scope: {name: '@', value: '='}
```

And in the template:

```
<property name="{{property.name}}" value="property.value">
```

Note that I removed the `{{}}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about `name='property.name'` and `scope: { name: '=', value: '=' }`?

This should do the magic.

To know more see [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and search(ctrl+f) for '@', the first result is what you want ;)

Comment: This creates an isolated scope for that directive which is sometimes an undesired effect.

Comment: I think you meant:

scope: { name: '@', value: '=name' }

This will put the string name in the 'name' hash, and the value in the 'value' hash

Comment: This works, but sets up a two-way binding, much like "pass by reference" instead of "pass by value" so beware: if the value is changed by the directive controller etc. it will modify your parent scope objects.